# Keep only dataframe rows where date is whole hour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with data in 15m intervals

`stock    fullname      open      high       low     close     volume                date
0  AAPL  Apple Inc.  206.3940  206.5050  206.0100  206.3040  2242259.0 2019-09-03 09:45:00
1  AAPL  Apple Inc.  206.3200  206.9500  206.2960  206.6900  1094447.0 2019-09-03 10:00:00
2  AAPL  Apple Inc.  206.6700  206.6700  204.3800  204.4200  1837739.0 2019-09-03 10:15:00
3  AAPL  Apple Inc.  204.4282  205.0963  204.4156  204.8282  1199631.0 2019-09-03 10:30:00
4  AAPL  Apple Inc.  204.8174  205.4500  204.5300  205.1924   959709.0 2019-09-03 10:45:00`

Question is, how do I keep only the whole hour rows? (eg. 2019-09-03 10:00:00)

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
df1 = df[df['date'].dt.strftime('%M:%S').eq('00:00')].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

First idea is test if minutes and seconds are `0`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = df[df['date'].dt.minute.eq(0) & df['date'].dt.second.eq(0)]
```

Or compare [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by hours by original column:

```
df1 = df[df['date'].dt.floor('H').eq(df['date'])]
print (df1)
  stock    fullname    open    high      low   close     volume  \
1  AAPL  Apple Inc.  206.32  206.95  206.296  206.69  1094447.0   

                 date  
1 2019-09-03 10:00:00
```